# How to call database in sqlite3? Getting a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, database, sqlite, cursor

I have a database in my server called `ex`.

So in my python script (where sqlite3 is imported) I will try to insert values...

```
try:
    # Initial setup runs one time
    connect = sqlite3.connect('ex')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
except Exception as e:
    error_string = e


# Insert query into the cursor 
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO student_urls (user_name,assignment,url,created_at) \
    values(?,?,?,date('now'))" ,(user_name,assignment, url))
```

But the cursor.execute line is giving me issues... In particular I get a 500 internal server error. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: 'Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.'

Comment: Sorry, quick question though. Did I correctly write connect=sqlite3.connect("ex")? Is it just "ex"?

Comment: I don't think this is something python related. You should write the whole database name, `ex` and `ex.db` are different. Maybe you don't have the authority of the dir.

Comment: So you mean, call it ex.db instead? Thanks

Comment: It depends. You should call what the file's name is. If there is no such a file. sqlite3 will create one for you.

Comment: In command line I first typed in 'sqlite3 ex'. That created the file named ex. Because I think what's confusing me is that I'm not sure if in the connection you call it "ex" or "ex.db"

Comment: Another thing that is confusing is that when I typed in `.databases` in sqlite, I got name to be **main** but the file is **\ex**. So what is the name of this file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34268/discussion-between-student-j-and-zhangyangyu)

Comment: It depends. You should call what the file's name is. If there is no such a file. sqlite3 will create one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the *full* path of your SQL database, as with `sqlite3.connect('/var/www/ex.db')`. Also, ensure that the application has sufficient read/write permissions. I encountered an identical problem when hosting my Flask app on a server, and had to both use a full path and `chmod -R` my app directory.